# How much data bandwidth can a 3G gsm cell tower can support?

Tags: 3g, cellular-internet

I was always wondering how many simultaneous users can a 3G tower supports with its data rates?
I mean they advertise 28.8Mb/Sec for the 3G Data but in reality if a lot of people use it say 10 , it wont give 288Mb/Sec bandwidth.
I didn't find anywhere where such information is published so I thought to ask here.
Don' know why the cell operators keep it such a secret :)

Comment: and how is 3G internet Bandwidth is not computer hardware related?

Answer (score -1):

(In the UK at least) data is given a lower priority than voice, so if there are a large numbers of people making telephone calls through the cell tower your data will have less of a priority.